# How To Compare My Actual MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 MasterPage in my project.

The `MasterPage to common pages` and the `MasterPage to PopUp pages`.

And I have a class `BasePage` that is inherited by all pages, and in BasePage I need to verify  which is the actual MaterPage that is used.

Ex:

`if(Master.GetType() == typeof(Master)` ....

How do I test it?

Comment: not quite making sense, can you try and explain a bit more?

Comment: I have 2 MasterPage in my project. The MasterPage to common pages and the MasterPage to PopUp PAges. And I have an class BasePage that is inherited by all pages, and in BasePage i need to verify whats the actual MaterPage used. Can you understand me?

Comment: Do you have custom types for both master pages? Why you can not use `getType() == typeof()` approach you've mentioned?

Comment: So, when I test it, the types are different. I have to compare my actual MasterPage with the type of class, of course?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `is` operator is handy for checking types.

If the two masters (I will call them MasterPage and MasterPagePopup) are inherited form a common ancestor (Page?) and not one another, you could do something like this:

```
if(Master is MasterPage) 
  { do some stuff; }
if(Master is MasterPagePopup)
  { do other stuff; }
```

The only gotcha is if one master is inherited from the other; if MasterPagePopup is inherited form MasterPage, then both cases above would be true for MasterPagePopup as he *IS* both a MasterPage and MasterPagePopup .  However, `if...else if` would solve this:

```
if(Master is MasterPagePopup)
  { do other stuff; }
else if(Master is MasterPage) // popup is already handled and will not hit this
  {do some stuff; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to check the type of your MasterPage is with the `is` keyword:

```
if (this.Master is MasterPageCommon) {

} else if (this.Master is MasterPagePopup) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to do

```
if(page.Master is PopUpMaster)
{
   //Do Something
}
else if (page.Master is NormalMaster)
{
   //Do Something
}
```